# Node app heroku deployment error

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I have this Package.json file for a node.js application which I want to deploy in Heroku.

`{
    "name": "timestamp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Node API project",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "author": "theokeles",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.14.0",
        "moment": "^2.17.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/ashishdutta007/fcc-timestamp-api.git"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/ashishdutta007/fcc-timestamp-api/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/ashishdutta007/fcc-timestamp-api#readme",
    "keywords": [
        "timestamp",
        "node.js",
        "microservice"
    ]
}`

But while deploying the buildlog throws the error "NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL =error".
The Heroku build.log file

```
-----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)  
       Resolving node version (latest stable) via semver.io...
       Downloading and installing node 6.9.1...
       Using default npm version: 3.10.8
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
      - node_modules
      - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
      ├── express@4.14.0
      └── moment@2.17.1
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 14.1M
-----> Launching...
       Released v5
       https://stormy-retreat-72893.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

I am unable to run my application
Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: That's just logging configuration, not an error. What does your Procfile look like?

Comment: Procfile contents : web: node index.js.
Thanks @pedrorijo91 my Heroku deployment is working now, it was not working because of some config vars in heroku